# Simple WSDL showing error "All operations specified in this binding must be defined in port type "

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am trying to write a simple wsdl file that has a inline xsd.
I am showing with the below errors.I refered other stackoverflow question, but none helped on this issue.Any help is appreciated.
Below is the code

```
<wsdl:types>
    <!-- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/createEmployee/">
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="..\schema\Employee.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema> -->
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Employee" 
                xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Employee" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="Employee" type="tns:EmployeeRequestType"></xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="EmployeeRequestType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="fname" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="lname" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="salary" type="double" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="EmployeeResponse" type="tns:EmployeeResponseType"></xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="EmployeeResponseType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="EmpId" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

```
<wsdl:message name="addEmployeeRequest">
    **<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Employee"/>**
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="addEmployeeResponse">
    **<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:EmployeeResponse"/>**
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="addEmployeePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="addEmployee">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:addEmployeeRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:addEmployeeResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="addEmp_Binding" type="tns:addEmployeePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="addEmployee">
        **<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://www.example.org/createEmployee/addEmployee" />**
        <wsdl:input name="addEmployeeRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="addEmployeeResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="addEmployeeService">
    <wsdl:port name="addEmployeePort" binding="tns:addEmp_Binding">
        <soap:address
            location="http://localhost:8080/service/addEmployee" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Errors :

```
Below are the errors at highlighted
```

1. The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'Employee' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.

2. The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'EmployeeResponse' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.

   3. The operation specified for the 'addEmp_Binding' binding is not defined for port type 'addEmployeePortType'. All operations specified in this binding must be 
      defined in port type 'addEmployeePortType'.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my question is that there was an issue with namespaces. Once I corrected the namespaces, the below errors were resolved:

1. "The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'Employee' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema."
2. "The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'EmployeeResponse' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema."